# Server socket accepts connection without listen

Tags: python, sockets

It has always been my understanding that it is **essential** for a server socket to *listen()* before it can accept connections.

However, this appears not to be the case.

```
import socket
import threading

ADDRESS = 'localhost', 10001
EVENT = threading.Event()

def server():
    with socket.create_server(ADDRESS) as _socket:
        #_socket.listen()
        EVENT.set()
        conn, _ = _socket.accept()
        with conn:
            print('Got client connection')

(_server := threading.Thread(target=server)).start()

EVENT.wait()

with socket.socket() as _socket:
    _socket.connect(ADDRESS)
    
_server.join()
```

Running this gives:

```
Got client connection
```

i.e., it worked without a call to listen() on the server socket.

There is no difference in behaviour if I invoke *_socket.listen()*

Is this something that's peculiar to Python or am I misunderstanding something fundamental?

Python 3.11.3 on MacOS 13.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`create_server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.create_server) is a convenience function. It has a *backlog* parameter and calls `listen` for you.

From the docs:

> … *backlog* is the queue size passed to socket.listen(); if not specified, a default reasonable value is chosen. …

Comment: Thank you. I did read that in the docs but misinterpreted it. I thought it meant that a backlog value would be use for a subsequent (explicit) call to *listen()*